# Select an object in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path, selections

Referring to [this svg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_9p-AXbU466Sob3OBk9N5eevZiLV9goq/view?usp=sharing):
There are 5 squiggles. Supposed I wanted to select one of them and the copy and paste it elsewhere. How do I do this? I've ungrouped it all but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked the file. These objects are a combined path. So, ungrouping will not separate them.  Ungrouping only works on groups, and this isn't a group.

You can tell if an object is a combined path or a group by selecting it, then check the Status Bar along the bottom. It will either say "Path" or "Group of x object".

Example showing difference between a compound path and a group in the Status Bar.

[image]

To separate a compound path, select the object, then and then do *Path > Break Apart*. Now you will be able to select just one shape, and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or *Edit > Copy*) then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or *Edit > Paste*).

Example showing separate objects after Breaking Apart.

[image]

If you want to recombine these paths after making a new shape, select them all and do *Path > Combine*.

Compound paths are sometimes used to turn a bunch of shapes into a single path for example if you need to use it with some kind of digital cutter, or for use as a pattern along a path.  If you aren't doing that, you could just group them instead.  Also note that a compound path can only have one fill and one stroke. Grouped objects don't have this limitation, and each object can have its own fill and stroke colour.